# How can I add horizontal line in highcharts js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihkrk.png)

Here's how to do it!

I can do with css position, but I don't need it.

Comment: can u please add more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For drawing any path on the chart you can choose [SVGRenderer#path](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path), there you can define coordinates and set attributes.

```
  Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
  ...
  }, function(chart) {
    chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 430, 'L', 800, 430])
      .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red',
        zIndex: 4
      })
      .add();
  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/54bx97no/